# Django: How to delete models in real time

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a subscriber confirmation system with Django, and I do not want random/spam subscribers. So I came up with a confirmation system. Once the subscriber clicks the subscribe button, a **Subscriber** model is created. However, it is not confirmed. I send a confirmation email and only if the subscriber clicks on the link in the email will the model be confirmed. The problem with this system is that an unconfirmed subscriber stays and is not deleted. How do I write a function that deletes the unconfirmed subscribers if they did not confirm in, say, 2 days?

models.py

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=True, null=True)
    #my function for deleting subscribers
    def confirm_date(self):
        today = date.today().toordinal()
        if today - self.ordinal_creation >= 2 and self.confirmed == False:
            self.delete()
```

Comment: Write a script (similar to ```confirm_date```)that removes all unconfirmed subscribers from your DB and schedule it to run let's say every 24 hours.

Comment: As suggested by @Ram, you need to create a function which is executed at periodic intervals of time. You can check `django-celery-beat`. Reference: https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat